# Number of curves obtained with ezcontour

Tags: plot, octave, contour

I'm trying to plot several curves with `ezcontour`. When I try this:

```
f = @(x,y) ((x).^2-1+(y).^2)./y;
h=ezcontour (f, [-5, 5],5);
```

I get this:

[image: Response]

And when I change to this:

```
f = @(x,y) ((x).^2-1+(y).^2)./y;
h=ezcontour (f, [-5, 5]);
```

I get this:

[image: Response 2]

What I want to obtain is several smooth curves shaped like at no. 1, which means I'd like to control the number of curves, their positions and their resolution.

Is it possible with Octave?

Comment: The function `contour` should allow you to customize all those things. You can’t with `ezcontour`.